# Push Array Items to Array type Column in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, backend

**This is a Controller in which I'm trying to catch multiple candidates id(ObjectId) and try to store it in the database in the array Candidates. But data is not getting pushed in Candidates column of Array type.**

```
routes.post('/Job/:id',checkAuthenticated,function(req,res){
var candidates=req.body.candidate; 
console.log(candidates);
Job.update({_id:req.params.id},{$push:{Appliedby : req.user.username}},{$push:{Candidates:{$each: 
candidates}}}
});
```

Console screens output

```
[ '5eb257119f2b2f0b4883558b', '5eb2ae1cff3ae7106019ad7e' ] //candidates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do all the `update` operations `($set, $push, $pull, ...)` in one object, and this object should be the second argument passed to the `update` method after the filter object

```
{$push:{Appliedby : req.user.username}},{$push:{Candidates:{$each: candidates}}
```

this will update the `Appliedby` array only, as the third object in update is reserved for the options (like upsert, new, ....)

you have to do something like that

```
{ $push: { Appliedby: req.user.username, Candidates: { $each: candidates } } }
```

then the whole query should be something like that

```
routes.post('/Job/:id', checkAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    var candidates = req.body.candidate;
    console.log(candidates);

    Job.update(
        { _id: req.params.id }, // filter part
        { $push: { Appliedby: req.user.username, Candidates: { $each: candidates } } } // update part in one object
    )
});
```

this could do the trick I guess, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me. Sorry for the late reply. :)

Comment: great, could you accept the answer, so anyone can find it helpful?

Comment: I have a reputation of less than 15 so it is recorded but not showing in public.

Comment: sorry, I meant accepting my answer, there is no restriction on this I guess, the restriction is on the upvotes, read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers